# Maximum diameter of convex cone of solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, spectral-theory

I am trying to find an upper bound for the maximum distance between 2 vectors that satisfy $$x, y \in \{s|As \geq 0 \text{ and } \lvert \lvert s \rvert \rvert_2 \leq L\}$$.
What is the maximum possible value of $$\lvert \lvert x - y \rvert \rvert_2$$. Do you guys knows of any upper bound of these values?

Comment: $2L$ comes to mind.

Comment: Yeah but is there a tighter bound using the structure of A?

Comment: I have the impression that you can tighten the bound if $\mathrm{Ker}(A)=\{0\}$. If there is a nonzero vector in the kernel of $A$ then $2L$ is tight.